# apache rewrite search url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple form with method get

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="category_name" value="cars">
<input type="text" name="location" value="newyork">
</form>
```

that redirect to this link:

```
http://my-site.com/search.php?category_name=cars&location=newyork
```

I would make a rewrite rule for become:

```
http://my-site.com/cars/newyork.html
```

I have try with this code but not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ search.php?category_name=$1&location=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first URL is of the format a browser sends an HTML GET form in – you can not change that server-side.

Comment: how resolve? it's possible by php redirect?

Comment: You can do an explicit redirect once the request reaches your server. Or you do it client-side, by not really sending the form the normal way, but reading the values with JS and create the URL manually.

Answer (score 0):

Including the rules that you have, try adding these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /search\.php\?category_name=([^&]+)&location=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2.html? [L,R=301]
```

Additionally, you may need to add a couple of conditions for the rules that you do have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ search.php?category_name=$1&location=$2 [R=301,L]
```